# C# operator overloading not working when passed as generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, operator-overloading

I added operators for == and != to a class but it seems that they are not called when a object of that type is passed as a generic parameter. When I look at the decompiled code it looks like (object)a == (object)b.

Is it possible to use the operator overloads in this scenario?
Thx!!

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test() {
  var a = new OperatorTest(13);
  var b = new OperatorTest(13);

  Assert.IsTrue(a==b);
  TestGenerics<OperatorTest>(a,b);
}

void TestGenerics<T>(T a, T b) where T: class {
  Assert.IsTrue(a == b); //THIS FAILS!
}

class OperatorTest {
  private readonly int _value;

  public OperatorTest(int value) {
    _value = value;
  }

  public static bool operator ==(OperatorTest x, OperatorTest y) {
    return x._value == y._value;
  }

  public static bool operator !=(OperatorTest x, OperatorTest y) {
    return x._value != y._value;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you override `==` and `!=`, you should also be overriding `.Equals`.